# Exporting Variable Importance Plot as Image

Tags: python-3.x, h2o

I am trying to export an image generated in a Jupyter notebook using the H2O library to a PNG file. The image is the variable importance plot

I have tried using the matplotlib export functionality but it generates an empty PNG file.

```
cv_gbm.varimp_plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the direct solution to your question, but the following steps should work:

```
gbm_var_imp = cv_gbm._model_json['output']['variable_importances'].as_data_frame()

x = gbm_var_imp['scaled_importance']
x.index = gbm_var_imp['variable']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
x.sort_values().plot(kind='barh')
fig.savefig('gbm_variable_importance.png', dpi=600)
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, the following should work ...
VarImp_model <- as.data.frame (h2o.varimp (model))
VarImp_model$variable <- factor(VarImp_model$variable) %>%
fct_reorder(VarImp_model$scaled_importance)

```
ggplot(VarImp_model[1:10,], aes(variable, scaled_importance))+
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Variable importance")+
  xlab("") + ylab("")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14), axis.text = 
         element_text(size=12), 
         plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=16), strip.text = 
         element_text(size=14))
```